# ValueError: Argument 'url' got value 'https://www.google.com' that cannot be converted to None when running the test

Tags: robotframework

Hi Anyone please help on this below queston,

when I run the robot script in pycharm getting below error

**ValueError: Argument 'url' got value 'https://www.google.com' that cannot be converted to None.**

[image]

Comment: What code did you actually run? I'm not familiar with robotframework

Comment: That code runs fine.
Are you using 3 spaces between the keyword and its arguments? I would use a simple txt file editor to create a browser.robot with the exact code as above (no copy paste, just type it).
It must be some kind of character conversion that is messing up the file